# Capture part or whole using regex with same capturing name

Tags: regex

Given the two following strings :

```
\06086-afde-4e46-8886-@xxx.com\0xxx7ccd-6293-4343-8e50-xxx

\0name.surname@xxx.com\0xxx6293-4343-8e50-e1d5-xxx
```

I try to extract `6086-afde-4e46-8886-` (id it is a guid) or `name.surname@xxx.com` (if it is not a guid). The difficulty here is that the captured groups must have the same name.

So far, I have
 `(?<name>(?:\w{4}-){4}|[a-zA-Z.]{1,}@xxx\.com),` but this also captures *7ccd-6293-4343-8e50-* or *6293-4343-8e50-e1d5-* which I don't want.

I was also thinking about something like `\\\0(?<name>(?:\w{4}-){4}|[a-zA-Z.]{1,}@xxx\.com)(?:(?:@xxx\.com)?\\\0),` 
but then is there a way not to repeat the xxx.com part (because it is more complicated than that). Also, this relies on finding `\\0`, which I'd like not to, as I don't really know if this will be found somewhere else in the string.

Thanks..

Comment: your regex works here http://regex101.com/r/jC3uR4/4

Comment: It works because it looks for '\0' at the beginning of the string. I'd like not to, as I could very well find this somewhere in the string, possibly in front of a guid I try not to catch

Comment: so you want the first match?

Comment: In your expression you have to test for `@xxx.com` in both cases, number and names. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27147662/4137828) for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regular expression is matching the number `6086-afde-4e46-8886-` and the email `name.surname@xxx.com` into the same group name without using the start sequence \0

```regex
(?<_name_>[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+@xxx\.com|(?:[\w]{4}-){4}(?=@xxx\.com))
```

This regular expression uses a positive look ahead `(?=@xxx\.com)` for matching the number without taking `@xxx.com`.

Comment: this does not work because it is not possible to have two capturing groups with the same name.

Comment: @RomainVergnory Why is it so important to have the same name?

Comment: The regex is part of a config file. the program using it expect a group named "name". The regex may change a lot between two configurations, but should always have a group named "name"

Comment: That's what I was looking for, positive ahead. Update your answer with just the second regex (as it is not possible to have two capturing groups with the same name), and you'll get the correct answer

Comment: @RomainVergnory Edited the answer. The first regular expression was not working for your solution, but it was a correct one. Not all regular expressions can be handled by all languages or commands.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
\\0(?<_name_>(?:[\w\-\.]+))@xxx\.com
```

And add all allowed characters inside the square parentheses

demo: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=be0fed5e-1d24-43cc-9db9-812311c17d61

Comment: This might have been confusing due to edits, but your regex does not work. For the second example, I need to extract `name.surname@xxx.com`. For the first one just `6086-afde-4e46-8886-`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to get the first match. If yes then try the below regex.

```
^.*?(?<name>(?:\w{4}-){4}|[a-zA-Z.]{1,}@xxx.com)
```

http://regex101.com/r/jC3uR4/5